# How can i disable typing in a Devexpress LookupEdit?

Tags: devexpress

I have a lookupedit and want to disable typing. The user needs to select from the dropdown only.

I have tried setting SearchMode property of the lookup editor to OnlyInPopup but doesnt seem to work .
Any idea how i can do this ?

Comment: does this help you?
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/cq49786/prevent-user-from-typing-in-lookupedit

Comment: Is TextEditStyle in LookupEdit selected as DisableTextEditor? If it is selected as Standard, select it as DisableTextEdit.